# Retrieve table from key

Tags: lua, lua-table

Is there a way to retrieve the table to which belongs the key from the key itself? For exampe

```
tbl { Italy = "Roma" }
```

Can I go back to tbl from Italy?

Answer (score 2):

No, but you can save the reference to the table itself in the element:

```
tbl = {}
tbl.Italy = {"Roma", tbl}
print(tbl == tbl.Italy[2])
```

prints `true`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you want to do for attributes (table fields) but you can do it with methods:

```
function tbl.getItaly(self)
     return self.Italy
end
```

Then `tbl:getItaly()` returns the Italy of tbl; in methods, `self` is given implicitly by Lua interpreter and represents the table that contains the called method. Note that you need to use colon not dot syntax.

Answer (score 0):

A key is any value other than `nil`. In this case, you have a `string` value: "Italy". No value has the general concept of "parent" or "owner". Nonetheless, you can create structures to which you apply that concept if you need to.

```
local capitals = {}
capitals.Italy = { capital = "Roma", collection = capitals }
capitals["Czech Republic"] = { capital = "Prague", collection = capitals }

local playwrights = {}
playwrights["William Shakespeare"] = { born = 1564, died = 1616, collection = playwrights }


local fact = capitals.Italy
print(fact.collection == capitals)
```